# display all values of a vector matrix in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a `vector< vector< pair<int,int> > >` and I want to print all its values
I tried doing this with 2 iterators, but failed miserably on the 2nd one:

```
vector< vector< pair<int, int> > > list;
vector< vector< pair<int, int> > >::iterator it1;
vector< pair<int, int> >::iterator it2;

for( it1=list.begin(); it1<list.end(); ++it1 ){
  for( it2=it1.begin(); it2<it1.end(); ++it2 ){
    printf("%d, %d", *it2.first, *it2.second);
  }
}
```

any ideas on how to traverse the second vector as well?
Thanks

Comment: Please use some `typedef`'s. :)

Comment: Note that no-one else seems to have spotted the uselessness of printf "%d, %d" in a loop. The numbers will glue together. My answer aimed to fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you meant something like this:

```
for( it1=list.begin(); it1 != list.end(); ++it1 )
{
  for( it2=it1->begin(); it2 != it1->end(); ++it2 )
  {
    printf("%d, %d", (*it2).first, (*it2).second);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add the declarations for `it1` and `it2` to get it to compile, of course.  (But "somthing like this" suggests you were just posting pseudo-code anyway, to give the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (it1 = list.begin(); it1 != list.end(); ++it1) {
    vector< pair<int, int> >& v = *it1;      
    for (it2 = v.begin(); it2 != v.end(); ++it2) {
        printf("%d, %d", (*it2).first, (*it2).second);
    }
}
```